# Is it possible to upgrade a k8s registered cluster in Rancher?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I'm considering to register a kubernetes cluster in Rancher. After that, how should I handle coming kubernetes upgrades? Can they be handled by Rancher itself?

I only found information about upgrading a k3s registered cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it from the cluster view (if your cluster was installed via rancher) as [documented](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/cluster-admin/upgrading-kubernetes/):

- From the Global view, find the cluster for which you want to upgrade Kubernetes. Select ⋮ > Edit.
- Expand Cluster Options.
- From the Kubernetes Version drop-down, choose the version of Kubernetes that you want to use for the cluster.
- Click Save.

Comment: As I remember, this solution only works for Rancher launching Kubernetes clusters, not for registered clusters and It depends on how he created the cluster (using kubeadm, eks, aks ...)

Comment: yeah, thanks. good point. let me make an addition to my answer